# PHP can't connect to MySQL Database (timeout)

Tags: php, mysql

I started experimenting with PHP and now I wanted to connect with a MySQL Database and have tried every way you can find on the Internet (mysqli and pdo), but every time the connection times out.
What i also need to say is that the Database is running on a external server and **not on localhost**

Comment: With that little information it is impossible to say what really is causing the problem

Comment: Hi bro! Show the code you have to help you

Comment: Thats my newest attempt:
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("server", "username", "password", "database");

   if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   echo "Connected successfully";
?>

Comment: _"server", "username", "password", "database"_ are the real credentials? You need the real ones

Comment: no no i changed them for this

Comment: im not that dumb

Comment: Please try this https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn Don't use mysqli in a new project.

Comment: The issue is most likely in `server`. I don't know what you replace it with, but it's probably not the right hostname

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Maybe the mysql server is simply not allowing external connections. Only localhost?

Comment: Ensure that the DB Server is allowing remote connections.

Comment: Have you mysql installed in your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're running your php code on your own machine and MySQL on a hosting service.

Many hosting services simply don't allow connections to MySQl from outside their private networks. Because cybercreeps. If that's your situation you need a different hosting service.

Others require some special configuration setting. It sometimes appears on cpanel as something like "Remote database access". Ask their tech support. And make sure you use the correct hostname when connecting.

If you are new to this stuff you may get the best setup for your learning by installing MySql locally. Trying to learn both database programming and the necessary network engineering for a remote connection at the same time? Huuuge pain in the xxs neck.  Can you install WAMP? Amps?